# Gaps in Cura's Slicing for Monoprice Select Mini V2

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, monoprice-select-mini

Why does this happen (circled in red), and how can I fix it? It is making my prints come out horrible.

Not shown in the picture, but the option "Coasting" was Enabled:

- Coasting Volume 0.064 mm<sup>3</sup>
- Minimum Volume Before Coasting: 0.8
- Coasting Speed 90%

---

[image: Rendered G-code view of a sliced model]

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3D Printing.SE Could you look at the option "coasting" and report the value?

Comment: Coasting was Enabled (Coasting Volume .064 mm^3, Minimum Volume Before Coasting: .8, Coasting Speed 90%). I've disabled it and it looks sane now. Feel Free to write an answer and I'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable the option "Coasting", the extruder will follow the extrusion path at the end of switching to the next layer or the next section, but will not deposit any material as it uses the build up pressure in the nozzle to deposit the final bits. This shows up in your G-code representation by empty (non-depositing) gaps (in reality, when fine-tuned correctly, will be filled).

*E.g. sliced without "Coasting" enabled:*
[image: Print without enabling the coasting option]

*E.g. sliced with "Coasting" enabled:*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar thing happen when slicing a large piece that has - in real life - walls of about 2 cm. By scaling it down to 1.5%, this become less than the wall thickness, and the wall was simply omitted by CURA.

In my experience, a model showing gaps *can* have in these locations a thickness less than 1 wall.

Comment: Yes that is true, but not the case in this example. Very nice addition to mention for people that may stumble onto this topic with wall thickness issues!